# Can't join Windows domain from different subnet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have a lab with Windows Server 2008 R2 acting as a domain controller for domain `win.testlab` with IP address `10.0.1.1`. I have several Windows Server 2012 VMs connecting to this domain within the same subnet with no problems. Windows Firewall is off. The network is `10.0.1.0/24`.

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine on network `10.0.2.0/24` called `LIME` with IP address `10.0.2.2` and I want to join it the `win.testlab` domain. I can ping the domain controller with no issues and when I run `net view \\10.0.1.1` I get a reponse back showing me the shares on the DC. All looks good.

Now, when I try and **join** the domain using the NETBIOS name of `WIN` it fails, but if I join with `win.testlab` it succeeds. Does that indicate something up with the router between the subnets? Do you know what? It's not causing any issues but it leads me to suspect a misconfiguration of the router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBIOS relies on broadcast name resolution. Routers don't generally forward broadcast traffic. I would expect this behavior in this scenario so I don't believe there's a problem with the router and what you're experiencing sounds perfectly normal.