# Multi-subnet cluster with two default gateways?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 failover cluster spanning two subnets. `10.0.1.0/24` and `10.0.2.0/24`. I also have network `10.0.0.0/24` connected to machines in both subnets which has access to the Internet. If I enable the interface to `10.0.0.0` on a machine in subnet `10.0.2.0` I cannot then ping machine `10.0.1.1` from it. I have to disable the `10.0.0.0` interface and then it works. It also works if I remove the default gateway from the `10.0.0.0` interface, but then I don't get internet (which I need for updates).

Any ideas on how to set up? I have full access to the network, routers and firewalls.

EDIT: I just asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/585208/cant-join-windows-domain-from-different-subnet) today also, has a bit more background.

Comment: With such a question, I don't get how you have full access to the network, routers, and firewalls to be honest.

Comment: It's a test lab, if you have an answer, please share.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple default gateways configured on the network cards and the default gateway on the 10.0.0.0 network doesn't have routes/connectivity to the other two networks. Can you post an ipconfig/all and a route print from both hosts and also post the routing table from your router. How about posting a network diagram?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'll post a network diagram, yeah might be easier for you to understand what I'm trying to do. Might be a couple of hours...

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because I don't know the answer to my own question? Supersilious lot you are. I thought this would be a community where people, you know, *helped* each other?

Comment: My problem was I hadn't drawn my network diagram. Once I had done that it was obvious what my problems were.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basic networking...which is why I posted my sarcastic comment.  If you have full access to routers/firewalls then I would hope you knew at least basic networking to set those up.

But regardless:

Enabling the NIC interface on the `10.0.0.0` subnet with a default gateway would cause the machine to have 2 default gateways which won't work.

Enabling it without a default gateway works because traffic the local routing table doesn't specifically know about would traverse the computers existing default gateway from the other NIC.

You said "I don't get internet" which leads me to believe the `10.0.0.0` network is the one with actual internet routing/connectivity.

You have MULTIPLE choices here, and I won't go into all of them, but ONE choice would be remove the default gateway on the `10.0.2.0` NIC and leave the DG on the `10.0.0.0` NIC.  That would allow internet access.  Then to get the route to the `10.0.0.1` network you would put back in a static route on the local server to get there.  If your old DG was `10.0.2.1` then make the route to the `10.0.0.0` network use that IP as its next-hop and it would work as it did before.

Other alternatives are to route everything on the L3 switches or routers themselves (meaning in your case allow the `10.0.2.0` network through either the router or if the problem lies on the firewall change it there so that it can now reach the internet), or you can do the same as I mentioned in the previous paragraph but instead of a static route on the server, fix the routing on the router/DG of the `10.0.0.0` network so that it knows about the `10.0.0.1` network and can route the traffic from the `10.0.2.0` network to the `10.0.1.0` network properly.

There are other more complex ways of handling it as well, but that's pretty simple enough to implement in a test lab environment.

Comment: One of the multiple choices would be to change the route priority on the 10.0.0.0 nic to be lower than the 10.0.2.0 nic.